# visual studio project template to extract sharepoint list

Tags: custom-list

I want to extract a sharepoint list and then want to use it as a template in visual studion.
Can you suggest from where i can download and add such a template into the visual studio.
Please help !!

Answer (score 2):

Hemant,

1- You can save the List as template:
   List Settings -> Save list as template

2- It will give you a form, once filled; will give you .stp file which you can download!

3- Once you have the .stp file, you can change the .stp file extension to .cab file

4- Open and extract the contents of .cab file, the stp configuration will be specified in a manifest.xml file within that cab file (note that there may also be some other files containing content etc.

5- Once extracted and modified, you can make it back into an stp file by using visual studio to create a cab file project (file -> new -> project -> setup and deployment projects -> cab project).

6- Once complete simply change the extension of the .cab file to .stp

Ref: 
[Opening and resealing Sharepoint .stp files](http://rnowik.com/Opening-and-resealing-Sharepoint-stp-files.aspx)
[Import list template STP file to Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093140/import-list-template-stp-file-to-visual-studio-2010)